# anybody know how to save image output from cells in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, image, artificial-intelligence, jupyter

unlike google colab i cant right click to save the image, i use vscode on a chromebook with linux beta, it would be helpful if you provide step-by-step instruction. I am also new to code and the notebook uses python

p.s this is for dall.e flow-jupyter

Answer (score 4):

[image: Screenshot of vscode cell]

On the right we have two options, first one is to expand image (or zoom) and second option is to save image.

But best option is to use code to save image instead of saving images manually.
For example, if you want save pandas graph, then

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # pandas uses matplotlib in the backend

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": list(range(50))})
df["a"].plot()
plt.savefig("test.png")
```